# Access Doorkeeper from action Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

Is there any chance to access authenticate Doorkeeper method from a rails action controller? I would like to skip authentication just for one of my actions('show') but if a specific condition aapplies I want to call the apiauthenticate method to do its job. So in the action 'show', first of all I check a condition, and if does not apply, then I need to activate the api_authenticate. I'm launching a test that should call api_authenticate and stop it there. But for some reason it keeps going on and it does not stop.

This is the code of my controller

```
skip_before_action :api_authenticate, only: :show

def show
  param! :id, String, required: true

  post = Services::Posts.find(params[:id])

  if  post.public
    @post = post
    @user_id = nil
  else
    api_authenticate 
    ap "it shouldnt get here if user is not logged in"
    user = current_resource_owner
    @post = Services::Posts.show(params[:id], user)
    @user_id = user.identity rescue nil
  end
end

#more actions....
```

And this is the api_controller.rb where I have the authenticate method

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # Check the user is authenticated
  before_action :api_authenticate

  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :route_error
  rescue_from ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, :with => :action_error
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :base_error if Rails.env.production?

  def api_authenticate
    doorkeeper_authorize!()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something similar. Haven't tested the below code, but it should work.

```
skip_before_filter :doorkeeper_authorize! , only: :show

def show
  param! :id, String, required: true

  post = Services::Posts.find(params[:id])

  if  post.public
    @post = post
    @user_id = nil
  else
    doorkeeper_authorize! 
    ap "it shouldnt get here if user is not logged in"
    user = current_resource_owner
    @post = Services::Posts.show(params[:id], user)
    @user_id = user.identity rescue nil
  end
end
```

The Api controller,

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  # Check the user is authenticated
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize! 

  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :route_error
  rescue_from ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, :with => :action_error
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :base_error if Rails.env.production?

  def doorkeeper_unauthorized_render_options(error: nil)
    response_hash = { status: false, description: error.description, expired: false }
    response_hash[:expired] = true if error.description == "The access token expired"
    { json: response_hash }
  end

end
```

If the problem persists, please add the params passed to the show action.